# Android layout issue - table/grid/linear

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to wrap my head around some basic layout issues in android. Here is what I want as my final goal:

[image]

As you can see, various fields set up like that. The fields get filled in based on XML data. There could be 1 set of fields, or there could be more.

I tried a tablelayout, but couldn't get it set up right even when layout_span for Field 7. It worked ok, but when I tried to change the widths of Field 1 thru 5, the spanned row below it didn't conform to the changes (not like an HTML table would).

The fields in each group need to lineup if there are more than one (see red lines in image).

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I should approach this?

Thanks.

---

Edit:
from Naveen Kumar (thank you!):

updated screen shot, look what happens if you make the text longer:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="42"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="43"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="42"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="43"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Naveen: Thanks, looks like getting close but still not quite. See screenshot of your code above (I edited question to display it)

Comment: For some reason, that code has rows 2 and 4 as LinearLayouts and 1 and 3 as TableRows. Try using one or the other (TableRow is the more practical, though) for all of them. Also (unlikely to be the problem but good practise), gravity should be center_vertical|left, not center|left.

Comment: i use it from my existing code that's why i did not delete these line check again it is only with table row

Comment: Naveen: it was looking great until I tried to make the text longer in the 2nd row (see updated screenshot in original question). That killed everything. From my original example, the text should be able to wrap under fields 2 and 3 with no problems.

Comment: in the 2'nd and 4th row use Linear Layout instead of Table row it will not affect the upper and lower row(1,3)

Comment: Thanks for updating your code, but it's still not working. I've updated your screen shot in the original question. As you can see, if I make the text longer in field 7, it's messing up the alignment of field 8.